# Calculating ranges using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm building a website for a client who will master songs for his customers. The order form needs to include prices for certain number ranges of songs. I would like to use javascript to calculate the totals. For example: 1-3 songs = $75 each, 4-6 songs = $65 each and so on. I see a text box for the input of the number and the rel-time calculation appear after it. Can anybody lend a hand. I've been wracking my brain over this for weeks. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service. The idea here is to help you with **your code** that isn't working as expected

Comment: Are you looking for something like, https://jsfiddle.net/6t97rdxd/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this code:

```js
var data = [
  {
   'lowerLimit' : 1, // if amount is between 1 - 3 then price per piece: $75
   'upperLimit' : 3,
   'price' : 75
  },
  {
   'lowerLimit' : 4, // if amount is between 4 - 6 then price per piece: $65
   'upperLimit' : 6,
   'price' : 65
  }
 ],
 songOrder;

function checkPrice(element){
 return ( (element.lowerLimit <= songOrder) && (element.upperLimit >= songOrder) );
}

function showPrice() {
  
 var output = document.getElementById('output'),
 price;

 songOrder = document.getElementById('song-amount').value;

 if(songOrder <= 0) return;
  
 if(data.find(checkPrice)) {
  price = data.find(checkPrice).price;
 } else {
  price = 50;
 }
 output.innerHTML = 'Total price: $' + songOrder * price;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <h3>Number of songs?</h3>
 <input type="number" id="song-amount">
 <button type="button" onclick="showPrice()">Calculate</button>
 <p id="output"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]